# Creating a submit button

Tags: forms, drupal-7, form-api

I can create the regular submit button in the form api but what if I want to do something like this

```
$form['required_text'] = array(
'#markup' => '<button name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" class="primary-submit submit"    id="edit-submit">Submit - markup 
<img src="/img/arrow.png">
</button>',

);
```

This does not send the form. What do I need to do or does it need to be an input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wahnt to use an [`image_button`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#image_button) type instead. Also at the moment you're not really using the form API properly, you *can* just add markup to the form like you're doing but it doesn't register the element in the form and thus won't run submit/validate handlers. Something like this would work:

```
$form['required_text'] = array(
  '#type' => 'image_button',
  '#value' => 'submit',
  '#src' => '/img/arrow.png'
);
```

With that element you'll get a an `<input type="image" />` with the correct image loaded in to it's source.

Hope that helps

Comment: That is the right answer, I know this option is available but was not really what I wanted. I would have liked to have preserved the html. Anyway it worked. Thanks